# How to install Titanium Module in android on Windows Platform

Tags: android, module, titanium

I am trying to install titanium module in android using windows.I placed the modules folder into main project along the resources but it is unable to detect that module in tiapp.xml.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the path in Windows 7  "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\modules" 
Just paste the module here and tiapp.xml will detect it.

Cheers